# How can I order the columns in UI-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a JSON that is coming in as something like

```
{
 x:1,
 y:2
}
```

Which means when I stick it on my ui-grid, the `x` column is first and the `y` column is second. However, I want the reverse: `y` then `x`.

How can I tell UI-grid to display `y` ahead of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `columnDefs`.

Define your grid in html like this:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

And your app code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.myData = [{
      "x": "1",
      "y": "2",

    }, {
      "x": "3",
      "y": "4",

    }];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData'
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        name: 'y'
      }, {
        name: 'x'
      },
    ];
  }
]);
```

Note how `columnDefs` uses `y` for the first column and `x` for the second one.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XxzvKg2gYEnWNT6RJBaN?p=preview)